# Comparing two function types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I cannot understand the current behavior of typescript typing. Can someone explain why it happens?

```
type FunctionType = (a: number, b: number) => void;

const foo: FunctionType = (a, b) => (a + b); // No Error!
const foo2 = (a: number, b:number): void => (a + b); // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'void'.(2322)

const a = foo(1, 2);

a.toString(); // Error: Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'void'.(2339)
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEBVzQLxQAUAhgFxQJwC2ARhAE4A0UN5ltDAlFHgHxQA3dKgAmAbgBQEpJgDOwKADN06cvGRpMOSDyLFmNbnz1QA1C06SZCeUpUAmXSTbU6TFqXZvO5IaJ78JGYWYlBS1rbEusrohACMzPaWUsQAdMDoAMrA9KgIAOaEyUA) is a playground

Comment: Covered in the docs: [Functions: Return type
void](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void)

Comment: Please move your comment to answer, I will mark it as a right answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function is returning `(a + b)` that's why it's complaining about `void`. You should do

```js
type FunctionType = (a: number, b: number) => number;

const foo: FunctionType = (a, b) => (a + b);
const foo2 = (a: number, b:number): number => (a + b);

const a = foo(1, 2);

a.toString();
```

`void` is used when nothing is returned.

Comment: So why doesn't TS complain on `foo` that is returning a `number` although it's type says that is should return nothing (`void`)?

Comment: because `(): void` is not the same as `() => void`.


`() => void` can return any value but it will be ignored.
`(): void` expects no returned value at all.

I've updated the answer as well.

Comment: Why is there a difference between `(): void` and `() => void`?